# South commands unexpectedly removed from Django's manage.py

Tags: python, django, django-south

I've been working on a django app and have been successfully using South. For some reason, I'm no longer able to access south commands via `manage.py`:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration appname
Unknown command: 'schemamigration'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Furthermore, `manage.py help` doesn't list any South commands.

I'm still able to import South just fine through `manage.py shell` and south is still in my `INSTALLED_APPS`. I'm running South 0.7.6, Django 1.4.1, and Python 2.7.3 in a virtualenv, and I've also tried recreating the virtualenv without luck. Any ideas?

SOLVED: After some more fiddling, I noticed that when I removed my app from `settings.py > INSTALLED_APPS` South functionality returned. So, I investigated some more...

I have `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` set in my `settings.py` that uses a `reverse()` lookup. The `reverse()` lookup was failing because `admin.py` was attempting to import a model that I had just deleted. This was the source of my South issue. To solve my problem, I deleted the offending import in `admin.py`, but I also tested wrapping my global variables in `settings.py` with `try/except`, which also worked.

I find it strange that `manage.py` fails silently when it chokes while importing `settings.py`. Is there a way to change this behavior? Also, is there a best practice for setting global variables in `settings.py`?

Comment: is your virtuanlenv activated?

Comment: once virtualenv is activated, do a pip freeze, and make sure south is installed

Comment: See your `settings.py` > INSTALLED_APPS. Do you see `south` in that list?

Comment: Yes - the virtualenv is activated. If I create a new project using the same virtualenv, I'm able to access south commands, so I don't think it's a problem with the virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, south is in settings.py > INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @user1669141 please consider moving your "SOLVED" section to an answer below and marking it as resolved.